# Why was a suggested edit with 2 reject reviews approved?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I had a suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21876176) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54072359) question.

The edit was first rejected . But then, I suddenlt saw that I had a +2 reputation change. I saw that my edit was approved even with these two rejects and **without an approving review neither from the OP nor from a moderator**. Why?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing the review result]

Comment: The edit was probably approved by the post author. Post owners have final say in edit approvals.

Comment: @yivi I cannot see an approve review there.

Comment: Seems like the appropriate [banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/348149) is missing. But I daresay that's what happened here. Actually, if I'm reading the description of how the feature works, the text is only added to the revision if the override results in a _rejection_. For approvals overrides, your suggested edit is marked as approved and the suggested edit goes forward.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The rejection was [overridden by the author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028). Normally, it would say that right at the top of the page, but some idiot blocked that from happening so the reason for the override didn't get recorded.

This was my fault: I was [fixing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198791/how-is-this-user-able-to-review-posts-so-long-after-they-were-completed-original/322015#322015) a [couple other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277131/not-getting-credit-for-improve-edit/321927#321927) bugs yesterday, and kinda forgot that suggested edit overrides existed. When I realized this, I submitted a patch to fix it immediately, and that rolled out last night. Still, for about 7 hours yesterday overrides weren't being attributed; all told, this ended up affecting about 13 suggested edits (one of which was overridden by me).

Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations! Is it still a bug I am not still seeing it? Or it is gonna to stay like this forever?

Comment: You can call yourself an idiot, but at the end of the day there apparently was no test which helped you to catch the regression.

Comment: @Gimby I prefer an spec.

Comment: Honestly, just writing down what I was doing would've worked - and did, eventually. I just got in a hurry and got sloppy.

Comment: The 13 reviews overridden without the fix in place are never gonna be quite right, @double-beep. The edits themselves should be fine though.